# blurred linear gradient background to solid color Css

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I want to set a left gray line background in the div to show this is a thread....like in twitter.

I almost got it, but the line looks blurred. How do I make it solid?

```css
.thread {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.thread {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
      transparent 0%, 
      transparent calc(25px - 2px), 
      #E9EBEE calc(25px - 2px), 
      #E9EBEE calc(25px + 2px), 
      transparent calc(25px + 2px), 
      transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="thread"></div>
```

Comment: I just dont know how to alllocate a solid 2px line at that position with minimal code like this one..do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this instead:

```css
.thread {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.thread {
  background:linear-gradient(#E9EBEE,#E9EBEE) 25px 0/4px 100% no-repeat;
  /* OR
  background-image:linear-gradient(#E9EBEE,#E9EBEE);
  background-size:4px 100%;
  background-position:25px 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="thread"></div>
```

Comment: this is just terrific. What does it means? `0/4px` thank you.

Comment: @joe i added more detail ;) the `/` is the separation between the size and position